# android passing image file path to A then to B and finally C acitivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android and to java trying to learn my way in.

Right now I am trying to achieve (A)Select image form gallery (B) show a preview and ( C ) activity is Uploading to server:

Select image form gallery and show a preview: done (achieved) by using below Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // call android default gallery

            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

            }
            });

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileUri = data.getData();
                filePath = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), fileUri);
                Intent imagePreview = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImagePreview.class);
                imagePreview.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
                startActivity(imagePreview);
    } 
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
 Cursor cursor = null;
 try {
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
     cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
     int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     return cursor.getString(column_index);
 } finally {
     if (cursor != null) {
         cursor.close();
     }}
```

}

And In ImagePreview.java

```
 Intent imagePreview = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = imagePreview.getStringExtra("filePath");
    displayImage(filePath);

private void displayImage(String filePath) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapHelper.decodeSampledBitmap(filePath, 300, 250));
```

Now According to my understanding, since the filePath is already a string, I should be able it pass it to uploadactivity.java as such

```
 private void upload(){
    Intent upload = new Intent(ImagePreview.this, UploadActivity.class);
    upload.putExtra("finalImage", filePath);
    startActivity(upload);
}
```

and in uploadactivity.java

```
Intent upload = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
   finalImage = upload.getStringExtra("finalImage");
```

By this I can get to UpoloadActivity and upload button is displayed but filePath is not passed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the same key for the extras:
upload.putExtra(**"finalImage"**, filePath);
upload.getStringExtra(**"filePath")**;

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the actual code has finalImage = upload.getStringExtra("finalImage"); still says Sorry, file path is missing

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
finalImage = upload.getStringExtra("filePath");
```

with

```
finalImage = upload.getStringExtra("finalImage");
```